# How To use xaml binding to realize clock notification?

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, xaml, inotifypropertychanged

I want to have a INotifyPropertyChanged Test. The following code works well. But I want to replace the cs-code-binding with xaml-binding.
The question is how to do it while not affecting the program's function.
Thanks for help!

XAML:

```
    <StackPanel Margin="5">
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Margin="5"/>
        <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Button x:Name="button" Margin="5" Content="UpdateTime" Click="button_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Code-Behind:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(this.textBox, TextBox.TextProperty, new Binding("TimeNow") { Source = clock });
        }

        Clock clock = new Clock();
        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((bool)checkBox.IsChecked) clock.TimeNow = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }

    class Clock : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private DateTime dateTime;
        public DateTime TimeNow
        {
            get { return dateTime; }
            set { dateTime = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `DataContext` property of the MainWindow to the Clock instance

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = clock;
}
```

and declare a Binding in XAML that uses the current DataContext as source object:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding TimeNow}"/>
```

---

As an alternative to creating a Clock member in code, you could assign the DataContext in XAML

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:Clock />
</Window.DataContext>
```

and access the Clock object in code behind like this:

```
((Clock)DataContext).TimeNow = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: I tested these two approach. Both work very very well. Thank you very much! Great!

Comment: You're welcome. Also note that those are the standard ways to set up Bindings in WPF. You'd always set a DataContext and not explicitly set the source object of a Binding unless there is a specific reason to do so.

Answer (score 1):

With the nuget packages `ReactiveUI.Fody` and `ReactiveUI.WPF` you can write a ViewModel

```
public class MainViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        var canUpdateTime = this.WhenAnyValue(e => e.MayUpdateTime);
        UpdateTimeCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create(() => TimeNow = DateTime.Now, canUpdateTime);
    }

    [Reactive] public bool MayUpdateTime { get; set; }
    [Reactive] public DateTime TimeNow { get; set; }
    public ReactiveCommand<Unit, DateTime> UpdateTimeCommand { get; }
}
```

and the View

```
<Window
  x:Class="ReactiveWpfApp5.MainWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ReactiveWpfApp5"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:ReactiveWpfApp5.ViewModels"
  Title="MainWindow"
  Width="800"
  Height="450"
  mc:Ignorable="d">
  <Window.DataContext>
    <viewModels:MainViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>
  <DockPanel>
    <StackPanel>
      <TextBox Text="{Binding TimeNow, Mode=TwoWay}" />
      <CheckBox Content="May Update Time" IsChecked="{Binding MayUpdateTime}" />
      <Button Command="{Binding UpdateTimeCommand}" Content="Update Time" />
    </StackPanel>
  </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

That is all

Comment: I tested it. Wonderful!! I know little about ReactiveUI. I'm learning form now on. Thank you vvery much!

Comment: I found ReactiveUI very useful!